# SCNVector4: Rotate on x-axis

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, cabasicanimation

I have a sphere and managed to rotate it. But unfortunately along the wrong axis.

My goal is a rotation like the earth along the x axis. Can you help me to apply this?

Here is my existing code:

```
let spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
        // Use from-to to explicitly make a full rotation around z
        spin.fromValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0))
        spin.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: Float(CGFloat(-2 * Double.pi))))
        spin.duration = 30
        spin.repeatCount = .infinity
        sphereNode.addAnimation(spin, forKey: "spin around")
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this

```
self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(self.imageView.layer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,1.0,0.0,0.0));
```

Comment: the image mapped on the sphere is already rotating. Just in wrong direction. I don't get what imageView is in your code?

Comment: this is a sphere image

Answer (score 0):

You're already have working solution:

```
spin.fromValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0))
spin.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: CGFloat.pi * 2))
```

If you wanna change direction, just change vectors :)

```
spin.fromValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: CGFloat.pi * 2))
spin.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0))
```

Comment: Yes it is rotating. But along the wrong axis. I don't understand what w is.

Comment: @netshark1000 Oh, to change axis - change x, y, z: rotate by `x` = `SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: CGFloat.pi * 2)`, rotate by `y` = `SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: CGFloat.pi * 2)`, rotate by `z` = `SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: CGFloat.pi * 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate your Earth model about X-axis using SceneKit's Transaction:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/model.scn")!
let modelEarth = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "model", 
                                          recursively: true)!

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 500           // animation in seconds
SCNTransaction.animationTimingFunction = .init(name: .default)
modelEarth.rotation.x = 1
modelEarth.rotation.y = 0
modelEarth.rotation.z = 0
modelEarth.rotation.w = 100 * Float.pi           // fourth component
SCNTransaction.commit()
```